# OpenLayers with Bing Maps: Where does the data come from?

Tags: maps, openlayers, bing-maps

The street name 'Goethestraße' (52.51623 13.51613) is not rendered correctly on Bing Maps (Göthestraße) of [OpenLayers](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/bing-maps.html).

[image: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/bing-maps.html]

What's the source of the data? I ask because Bing shows the proper street name:

[image: https://www.bing.com/maps/?FORM=Z9LH3]

Comment: There is a really good chance that they use OpenStreetMap for their base data. You could create an account there and edit the spelling.

Comment: OpenStreetMap seems to use the correct data: Goethestraße. See https://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=52.51623%2013.51613#map=17/52.51578/13.51592

Comment: Bing Maps does not use OpenSteetMap data due to licensing restrictions. The map data for Germany in Bing Maps comes from HERE maps.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the issue is that OpenLayers is pointing to the older static map tiles of Bing Maps and not the dynamic tile service. As such they are retrieving older map tiles that have errors that have since been corrected in Bing Maps.

Edit (based on @rbundritt's comment below): When configured with `imagerySet: 'RoadOnDemand'`, `ol.source.BingMaps` displays the up-to-date dynamic tiles.

Comment: OpenLayers uses the REST API's "Get Imagery Metadata" service to get urls and metadata for the tiles (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701716.aspx). This should return the latest tiles, no?

Comment: Right, and they are pointing at the wrong imagery type. The Road imagery type in the REST services uses the older static map tiles. This hasn't been updated as pointing to the new dynamic tiles would cause issues for many existing applications out there that use those tiles. There is a new imagery type called RoadOnDemand which they need to use which will pull in the new tiles. Eventually the Road imagery set will be moved over to the dynamic tiles, but there will be a lot of hand holding with large companies to ensure nothing breaks on their end.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification @rbrundritt.